# Fatal error when loading the webform after upgrade

Tags: webform-civicrm

All the webform stopped working after we upgrade the webform_civicrm module from 6.2.1 to 6.2.2

Drupal: 9.5.2
CiviCRM: 5.57.1

Error in drupal log:

```
CRM_Core_Exception: Unknown api parameter: setRelationship in Civi\Api4\Generic\AbstractAction->__call() (line 234 of /var/www/html/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/Api4/Generic/AbstractAction.php).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue and reported at https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm/issues/3336269

The fix is available at https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/835